# Google Oauth2.0 API for mobile side sign in and server side access of the user content

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, google-people-api

I am working on an app in which android app asks user for the authentication and after authentication i am storing the authToken in database to access users content in future. On server to get accessToken from authToken I need client secret but in case of android auth2.0 client there is no secret, so how i can get accessToken form authToken and refreshToken.

Comment: Pls read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998335/how-to-get-access-token-after-user-is-signed-in-from-gmail-in-android)

Comment: @dgoku, Have you resolved this issue? I am also facing same problem.