# How to create Credential after Google Sign-In

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, google-api, android-youtube-api

For the Google Sign-In, I followed the sample code they had in the [github](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin/ServerAuthCodeActivity.java). I was able to get a google sign in working. I got Auth code and ID token, but I didn't know how to setup a web server for getting the refresh token/access token so I used a [work around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998335/how-to-get-access-token-after-user-is-signed-in-from-gmail-in-android).

```
                                // TODO(user): send code to server and exchange for access/refresh/ID tokens.
                                // [END get_auth_code]

                                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                                RequestBody requestBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                                        .add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
                                        .add("client_id", serverClientId)
                                        .add("client_secret", serverClientSecret)
                                        .add("redirect_uri","")
                                        .add("code", authCode)
                                        .add("id_token", idTokenString)
                                        .build();
                                final Request request = new Request.Builder()
                                        .url("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")
                                        .post(requestBody)
                                        .build();
                                client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(final Request request, final IOException e) {
                                        Log.e("tag", e.toString());
                                    }

                @Override
                public void onResponse(Response response) throws IOException {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response.body().string());
                        final String message = jsonObject.toString(5);
                        Log.i("tag", message);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
```

I was able to get the refresh and access token, but how do I create a credential for the Youtube API? I'm following the sample they have for upload video, and they use a completely different flow in the [Auth class](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/Auth.java) for credentials.

I found this from the documentation but I don't know what I need to set for the TokenResponse and what I'm supposed to use for the token server URL. Could someone clarify what to do next???

```
public static Credential createCredentialWithRefreshToken(
  HttpTransport transport, JsonFactory jsonFactory, TokenResponse tokenResponse) {
      return new Credential.Builder(BearerToken.authorizationHeaderAccessMethod()).setTransport(
    transport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setTokenServerUrl(
        new GenericUrl("https://server.example.com/token"))
      .setClientAuthentication(new BasicAuthentication("s6BhdRkqt3", "7Fjfp0ZBr1KtDRbnfVdmIw"))
      .build()
      .setFromTokenResponse(tokenResponse);
  }
```