# Access google photos API via Java

Tags: java, google-photos

I am very new to google API and I am having troubles with it. I red documentation [Google photos API for Java](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/guides/get-started-java), then I created OAuth credentials in google API console and downloaded it (credentials.json file).
After that I tried to access google photos. Here is code from documentation:

```
// Set up the Photos Library Client that interacts with the API
PhotosLibrarySettings settings =
   PhotosLibrarySettings.newBuilder()
  .setCredentialsProvider(
      FixedCredentialsProvider.create(/* Add credentials here. */)) 
  .build();

try (PhotosLibraryClient photosLibraryClient =
    PhotosLibraryClient.initialize(settings)) {

  // Create a new Album  with at title
  Album createdAlbum = photosLibraryClient.createAlbum("My Album");

  // Get some properties from the album, such as its ID and product URL
  String id = album.getId();
  String url = album.getProductUrl();

 } catch (ApiException e) {
    // Error during album creation
 }
```

But I don't understand how to create `Credentials` object to pass it to the `FixedCredentialsProvider.create()` method

Could you please provide me with some explanation/links about it?

Comment: You might want to have a look at the samples https://github.com/google/java-photoslibrary/tree/master/sample  and check that file https://github.com/google/java-photoslibrary/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/google/photos/library/sample/factories/PhotosLibraryClientFactory.java

Answer (score 4):

You can create a UserCredentials Object and pass it

```
UserCredentials.newBuilder()
        .setClientId("your client id")
        .setClientSecret("your client secret")
        .setAccessToken("Access Token")
        .build()
```

Go through this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54533855/6153171

Or check out this complete project on github
https://github.com/erickogi/AndroidGooglePhotosApi

Comment: @Kogieric I have a question in below link. I can't authenticate access because I don't have refreshToken when request to google. Do you have any solution for this? Thanks.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/issues/249

Comment: @Hoang You can get access token by calling https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token  and providing  client_id, client_secret

Answer (score 2):

The [`FixedCredentialsProvider.create(..)`](http://googleapis.github.io/gax-java/0.2.0/apidocs/com/google/api/gax/core/FixedCredentialsProvider.html#create-com.google.auth.Credentials-) call takes in a [`com.google.auth.Credentials` object](http://googleapis.github.io/google-auth-library-java/releases/0.9.0/apidocs/com/google/auth/oauth2/UserCredentials.html). For the Google Photos Library API, this should be a `UserCredentials` object, that you can create [`UserCredentials.Builder`](http://googleapis.github.io/google-auth-library-java/releases/0.9.0/apidocs/com/google/auth/oauth2/UserCredentials.Builder.html) that is part of the [Google OAuth library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java). There you set the refresh token, client ID, client secret, etc. to initialise the credentials. Getting a refresh token requires your app to complete the 
[`GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-java-client/releases/1.25.0/javadoc/com/google/api/client/googleapis/auth/oauth2/GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.html) that prompts the user for authorization and approval.

You can check out the sample implementation on [GitHub](https://github.com/google/java-photoslibrary/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/google/photos/library/sample/factories/PhotosLibraryClientFactory.java#L61), but this is the relevant code:

```
  GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
        new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport(),
                JSON_FACTORY,
                clientSecrets,
                selectedScopes)
            .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR))
            .setAccessType("offline")
            .build();
    LocalServerReceiver receiver =
        new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(LOCAL_RECEIVER_PORT).build();
    Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    return UserCredentials.newBuilder()
        .setClientId(clientId)
        .setClientSecret(clientSecret)
        .setRefreshToken(credential.getRefreshToken())
        .build();
```

There are a few moving parts involved, but the Google Photos Library API client library works with the [Google Authentication library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java) to handle OAuth authentication.

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to connect to the Google Photos API via the Google Sign-In for Android ? When the the latter is already integrated it seems redundant and error prone to go through this routine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33998335/how-to-get-access-token-after-user-is-signed-in-from-gmail-in-android to create the UserCredentials

Comment: @Jan-Felix Schmakeit: I have a question about your above code and it was description in below link. I can't authenticate access because I don't have refreshToken when request to google. Do you have any solution for this? Thanks. 

https://github.com/googleapis/google-oauth-java-client/issues/249

Comment: @Jan-Felix Schmakeit  ,  I have a problem when create UserCredential. With Android app , Oauth 2.0 Clien doesn't have **client secret**, even in json file. Do you have any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand about OAuth 2 first:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-oauth-2

Then you can look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54533855/6153171

P/s:
1. Grant Type: Authorization Code
Google developer console : credential is web client.

GoogleApiClient -> addScope, requestServerCode -> grand permission -> get account -> getServerAuthenCode -> get AccessToken (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54533855/6153171) 
-> I tested and it works well. You can follow this way

2. Grant Type: Implicit
   Google developer console : credential is android or ios app.

GoogleApiClient -> addScope, requestTokenID -> grand permission -> get account -> getTokenID -> get AccessToken. I didn't try successfully to grant authorization for google photo api. But with firebase authentication, we can use this way because firebase support class util for us.