# How to fetch photos from 'Google Photos' and display them in my app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, photo

I developed a feature which fetch all photos from device gallery.
and display them in a list in my app.
Now im required to fetch photos from 'Google Photos'
I can't seem to find a simple way to achieve it.

Comment: Try to search for an API

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Google Photos Library API client library works with the [Google Authentication Library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-auth-library-java) to handle OAuth authentication.

[StackOverflow answer for using Google Photos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52826328/13533028)

[Github Gist on Using GoogleCredentials for Photos](https://github.com/google/java-photoslibrary/blob/main/sample/src/main/java/com/google/photos/library/sample/factories/PhotosLibraryClientFactory.java#L61)